# Buildfire - How to get rid of thumbnail component defaults

Tags: buildfire

I am using the BuildFire thumbnail component.  In the documentation it says that the constructor either takes a url string, or an object with optional properties to augment the presentation of the component.  Two of these properties in the settings object are title and dimensionLabel.

Are the defaults hardcoded currently to override anything passed in?  I have passed settings objects with different titles and dimensionLabels, and still get the defaults.  Is there a way to completely get rid of the title?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Docs: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-Thumbnail-Component
Here is the source code: https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/blob/master/scripts/buildfire/components/images/thumbnail.js

looks like these are your 3 options

```
{
imageUrl : ""
title : ""
dimensionsLabel : ""
}
```

Comment: I have tried using those exact configuration parameters and the title still shows.

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide them?

Comment: Yeah, I would like to hide the title completely.

Comment: I'm not sure that is an option right now. You can easily copy the original file and change your local copy to make it do anything you want